# How to perform hybrid individual user account/aad authentication in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that is used by different customers. Currently the app is set up to use individual user accounts. I have built some authorization logic around that and would like to keep the logic unchanged.

I got a request that some of the customers would like to perform authentication for their users with their Azure Active Directory. I have uncommented the app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication part from Startup.Auth.cs. I registered the app as multi-tenant in my AAD. I managed to get the whole thing running and users now have the possibility to link their accounts with AAD and use it for authentication.

However, I encountered a few problems I am struggling with:

1. In order for the user to link his account with AAD he needs to set up an individual login/pass account in the first place. How can I avoid that? I want to have the users either authenticating with login/pass or with AAD, not both at the same time.
2. I have no control over which account the user uses to authenticate. Let's assume I expect the user to use an account in domainx.com, but if they link domainy.com account it will still work. I need to have some kind of way to compare the expected domain with the actual one that comes back from AAD. How can I do that?
3. One of the ideas to tackle the problem was to have a customer admin create the user accounts for them. The issue is that in AspNetUserLogins I need to store the user's AAD ID, not the email. How can I query AAD to check the UserID based on the email?